# Hardware and Software Restrictions for Android Devices

Tags: android, security

For some security issues, we need to disable some hardware components on an Android Device, and also disable app installations.
By hardware components i mean disabling bluetooth, wi-fi,microphone, camera and USB. One way is to use a custom kernel and disabling these features. Can you recommend an easy way to restrict Android Devices?

Comment: For me the quickest way would be using `App Lock`. It does most of the work Link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock

Comment: App Lock can be removed by root isnt it? It should be impossible or difficult as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to enforce restrictions on Android devices remotely and in bulk is by using a [Mobile Device Management](http://www.mobiledevicemanagement.io/mobile-device-management/) software. You can enroll the devices and also apply the management policies over the air.

All your requirements can be met by this solution. There are many vendors in the market currently, all you have to do is choose the one which suits you best. The giants in the field are airwatch, mobileiron, blackberry etc.

Hope this helps.